# How to debug a custom MigrationSqlGenerator

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

is there a way to debug a custom MigrationSqlGenerator? The Problem is, that it is executed by the update-database command in the package-manager-console ...

Wishes,
Manfred

Comment: You can attach a different visual studio to the visual studio running update-database your you can put `Debugger.Launch();` in your `MigrationSqlGenerator`....